# angular grid slowness using mat-table having 150 editable columns and 1500 rows

Tags: angular, angular-material-table, angular-cdk-virtual-scroll

We have requirement to show grid which can have 1500 rows and each row can have update 150 columns
This grid is implemented using angular mat-table, on-load entire grid is read only

Problem is, when just single row is editable with 150 form controls active.
The UI is lagging a lot and typing single char is a cell is taking few secs.

With same Grid, 1500 rows when I reduce columns. It performing much better.

How can we optimize grid performance horizontally?

we are trying using cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport; but there is no performance improvement

// table column
        // we have around 120 column in each row.

Comment: can please share some code of block in stackbliz link to test & give you appropriate help. Basic thing to keep in mind that when working with bulky data we need to think about pagination concept which is might be help you a lot.

Comment: we are trying to use  but not much improvement <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="25" class="scroll-view">
        <table
          mat-table
          [dataSource]="dataSource"
          cdkDropList
          cdkDropListOrientation="horizontal"
          (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
          matSort
          matSortDirection="asc"
        >

Comment: are you able to share code with stackbliz ?